# jquery filter on tag type and id

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I would like to select all inputs excluding specific inputs by ID, the filter I have at the moment works for selecting all inputs that are not checkboxes or buttons, but I want to also exclude inputs with certain id's but how?

Current filter:

```
objInputs = $("INPUT:NOT(:CHECKBOX,:BUTTON)");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use add the ID selector in `:not()` selector to exclude them

```
objInputs = $("input:not(:checkbox,:button,#SomeID)")
```